# What is maximum number of concurrent connection to Apple Notification Service

Tags: iphone, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

My application require to send many notifcation messages. Thus, i wonder how many concurrent connection I can open to Apple Notification Service?

Comment: As @Nick has said, there will be no such quantity that is allowed for this. Perhaps you could trial it on the sandbox and see how it reacts - but then again, the sandbox and live APNS servers are likely to be configured differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation does not specify a limit to the number of socket connections you can make with Apple's Push servers. From experience though, you can send a tremendous amount of messages through just one connection (100s of 1000s per minute if not more). That being said, you can certainly open more connections. Just make sure to check for eventual disconnects that may occur.